# Singleton HttpClient handling

Tags: dotnet-httpclient

I am using a singleton instance of HttpClient to make my calls. I was wondering is there a way to test if the HttpClient is valid? Can this instance of HttpClient go bad during the life of the application where there would be a need to create a new instance. My code is as follows

```
public class HttpClientWrapper : IHttpClientWrapper
{
    private Uri _baseAddress;
    private int _connectionTimeout;
    private HttpClient _httpClientInstance;
    private HttpClient HttpClientInstance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_httpClientInstance == null)
                _httpClientInstance = CreateHttpClient();
            return _httpClientInstance;
        }
    }
    public HttpClientWrapper(Uri baseAddress, int connectionTimeout)
    {
        _baseAddress = baseAddress;
        _connectionTimeout = connectionTimeout;
    }
    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsJsonAsync<T>(string requestUri, T      value)
    {
       //Test the instance before using it. What should be the test??
       return HttpClientInstance.PostAsJsonAsync<T>(requestUri, value);
    }

    private HttpClient CreateHttpClient()
    {
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            UseDefaultCredentials = true
        };
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(_connectionTimeout);
        client.BaseAddress = _baseAddress;
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new  MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        return client;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HttpClient is designed to be reused. It is not like the old days with WCF and ChannelFactory where the channel could become in a faulted state and had to be recreated.

> **HttpClient** is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout the life of an application. Especially in server applications, creating a new HttpClient instance for every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy loads. This will result in SocketException errors.

Ref: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Comment: Thanks Micheal, but I was wondering while reusing the HttpClient, does the client go corrupt during usage and is there a way to identify that? In other words would there be any reason to re-instantiate the singleton instance of the HttpClient being used in the application during the life of the application?

Comment: No, there should be no reason for re-instantiating the `HttpClient`. As far as I know and have experienced, the `HttpClient` is stateless.